# Powershell export AD users and memberships to a DataWarehouse

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm rewriting a script in Powershell to export all users from Active Directory to a Data Warehouse by REST Webservices.
My old script was based on LDAP protocol and the System.DirectoryServices .dll.
In this script, for each user, I had to check the membership with different groups.
For this, I selected the "memberof" propertie and did a inclusion test with the group name and the memberof attribute.

For 6.500 users, it takes about 1 hour long to complete the script.
The big part of the time spend is due to the business code executed in the webservice and the inclusion test.

Now, I would like to use the Active Directory module and the Get-ADUser command.
It will be cool if I can optimise the duration of the execution of the script.

I count 3 options:
- I continue with the test on the "memberof" attributes and the "contains" operator.
- Use Get-ADMembership for each user (must be very long!).
- Stock all memberships (just the users logins) in a matrix before selecting users and check the memberships for each user in this matrix.

I'm a noob in Powershell so if you have best practices for that it will be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely querying all the group's memberships, then saving those into arrays, then checking the arrays for each user will be MUCH faster than querying AD for that information over and over again.

Comment: What Nathan said is correct.  It will be WAY faster if you do one large query and get all the users and memberships into arrays and just do your checks against the arrays rather then querying AD everytime.

Comment: I'm agree but what about searching in the memberof attribute instead of using a matrix (I have a lot of AD Groups to check for each user)?

Comment: Groups can be nested (user1->group1->group2), so getting an array of all groups with their members and write code to connect nested groups etc. would probably be the best approach. If you only want direct memberships, then it doesn't really matter, but I don't think you would see any big difference in performance with members (group) vs memberof (user)